# SSL Error on attempting facebook authentication with LWUIT android port

Tags: android, ssl, lwuit, facebook-authentication

I've been having some trouble with a LWUIT application that I am attempting to port to android. The application has some facebook integration features which requires authentication. The J2ME and Blackberry builds function correctly. However on Android, the application freezes after the call to FaceBookAccess.authenticate() and shows a blank white canvas. In addition, LogCat gives me the following error message;

> 01-21 21:55:17.234: W/System.err(26776): java.io.IOException: SSL handshake failure: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
>   01-21 21:55:17.234: W/System.err(26776): error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:604 0xaf086860:0x00000000)
>   01-21 21:55:17.264: W/System.err(26776):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.nativeconnect(Native Method)
>   01-21 21:55:17.264: W/System.err(26776):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:316)
>   01-21 21:55:17.264: W/System.err(26776):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.getSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:168)
>   01-21 21:55:17.264: W/System.err(26776):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:399)
>   01-21 21:55:17.264: W/System.err(26776):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.sendRequest(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1325)
>   01-21 21:55:17.264: W/System.err(26776):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.doRequestInternal(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1656)
>   01-21 21:55:17.264: W/System.err(26776):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.doRequest(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1649)
>   01-21 21:55:17.264: W/System.err(26776):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1374)
>   01-21 21:55:17.264: W/System.err(26776):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:117)
>   01-21 21:55:17.272: W/System.err(26776):     at com.sun.lwuit.io.impl.PlatformImplementation.getResponseCode(PlatformImplementation.java:170)
>   01-21 21:55:17.272: W/System.err(26776):     at com.sun.lwuit.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:245)
>   01-21 21:55:17.272: W/System.err(26776):     at com.sun.lwuit.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:222)
>   01-21 21:55:17.272: W/System.err(26776):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

The behaviour was replicated on both emulator (2.1 and 3.0) and a Samsung Galaxy S running the 2.2 build.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this issue; it was not really a bid deal, I justed used the official facebook android sdk instead of the default lwuit api.